# Errno 22:invalid mode('rb') or filename:' ' while running a spec file while using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, ioerror

This is my spec file

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
a = Analysis(['final_code.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Python27\\PyInstaller-2.1\\final_code'],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=None,
             runtime_hooks=None)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      Tree('C:\\Python27\\data_req\\'),
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='final_code.exe',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=False )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=None,
               upx=True,
               name='final_code')
```

I have modified it to include the text files required. I am running it using the below command

```
pyinstaller.py final_code.spec
```

in my command prompt.

The error I get is

```
[Errno 22] invalid mode('rb') or filename:' '
```

Comment: can you please update the bug with the line causing the issue? And maybe pyinstaller.py as well?

Comment: Also shouldn't you be using `python pyinstaller.py final_code.spec` ?

Comment: It works without python too. It worked after reinstalling pywin32. But now when I run the .exe file it is giving 'python27.dll not found'. I checked and the dll is present, still it is giving the error. I even installed dll fixer but it is still giving the same error.

Answer (score 7):

I have come across a similar error when I use "\\" in the path on a Windows system.

Example:

```
a = Analysis(['final_code.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Python27\\PyInstaller-2.1\\final_code'],
           ....
exe = EXE(pyz,
      Tree('C:\\Python27\\data_req\\'),
```

Instead of that the double slash, try `pathex=['C:/Python27/PyInstaller-2.1/final_code']` and `Tree('C:/Python27/data_req/')`.

I believe the issue is with the type of slash being used: "/" vs "\".

`py_compile.compile('E:\\python_coe\\PythonInput.py','wb')` gave me the same error, but changing it to `py_compile.compile('E:/python_coe/PythonInput.py','wb')` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the first tweak worked.

1. Try running the command prompt in the admin mode.
2. Try re-installing pywin32

Comment: But now when I run the .exe file it is giving 'python27.dll not found'. I checked and the dll is present, still it is giving the error. I even installed dll fixer but it is still giving the same error.

Comment: exe-file x64 and python27dll - 32bit?

Comment: Check for your Python27 ell using this.

`import subprocess
print subprocess.check_call("where python27.dll")
`


If you don't get an O/P or get an error. Download a python27.dll file and paste in this directory:
C:\Windows\System32\