# IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename

Tags: python-2.7

I am a beginner at python and trying to use a very simple `shutil` module (`shutil.copy`) to copy databases from multiple folders into a backup folder. I am getting the error below. Any help is appreciated.

```py
# importing os module  
import os

#import time module
import time
import datetime

# importing shutil module  
import shutil 


now = datetime.datetime.now()
timestamp = str(now.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"))

source5 = "F:/SHARED/SOP/PRE GO LIVE/TEST CASES & SCENARIOS/MASTER/PRE_GO_LIVE_MASTER.accdb"

dest5 = "F:/SHARED/SOP/SB/Python/Destination/PRE_GO_LIVE_MASTER.accdb_"+timestamp+".accdb" 

print("Before copying ")

DB5 = shutil.copy(source5,dest5)

print("After DATABASE has been copied")

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sbasava1\Desktop\Python\Final_Attempt.py", line 101, in <module>
    DB5 = shutil.copy(source5,dest5)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 119, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename:
```

Comment: Please include the code that generated this error in your question.

Comment: I have now included the code for your review. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Check your file path, use *double* backslashes `\\` or a *single* forward slash `/` or make your string a raw string `r"..."`.

```py
# Original path - wouldn't work
path = "c:\location\directory"

# Raw string - would work
path = r"c:\location\directory"

# Double slashes - would work
path = "c:\\location\\directory"

# Forward slashes - would work
path = "c:/location/directory"
```

Consider learning about [string literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)

If this didn't help leave me a comment, it would also help to see the/part of the code you are working with!

**Edit**: Running your script didn't give me an issue:

[image: Screenshot]

Check if the directory you are trying to create a file in actually exists

Comment: Linking a relevant answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34704318/28360

Comment: I used Double slashes in the source and destination path and still no luck. Also tried the forward slash and it didnt help. How do you handle folder names that have spaces ? I have now added code for review

Comment: I just ran your script and it worked fine. Does `F:/SHARED/SOP/SB/Python/Destination` exist?

Comment: I am trying to copy access databases .